# Sound plays when run from CMD, but not when run as just the Jar

Tags: audio, jar, cmd

I don't know if this is really a Java question, but when I run my game from a batch file:

```
@Echo Off
Echo Starting Game
java -jar JailEscape.jar
pause
```

, so that I can see error messages, the sound in the game plays fine. However, when I just double-click the Jar, no sound plays, but everything else works like it should.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Ok, so this may be system specific since the sound works on my mom's mac, but why isn't working on my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have perhaps been by an incompatibility between different versions of the SDK and the RE. A reinstall of Java fixed the problem.